# Date.UTC failed to show correctly

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client method tries to return `Thu Mar 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)` but it it returning `Thu Mar 09 2017 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)` instead.
How can it be fixed? thx

```js
    dateToISO: (date) => { // date format in YYYY-MM-DD like "2017-03-09"
      const dArr = date.split('-');
      return new Date(Date.UTC(parseInt(dArr[0]), parseInt(dArr[1]) - 1, parseInt(dArr[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I try to reproduce it, that actually seems like a bug in the Date.UTC function.

I was trying to do:

```
console.log("Unmanipulate: " + new Date(Date.UTC(97, 4, 13, 0, 0)));
console.log("Manipulate: " + new Date(Date.UTC(97, 4, 13, -3, 0)));
```

Which return:

```
Unmanipulate: Tue May 13 1997 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT)
Manipulate: Tue May 13 1997 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT)
```

Look like the time zone is pass to the hour params, which is really weird. maybe I'm missing something.

You can read more about the spec of this function [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.utc).

I would recommend use [Moment.js](https://www.momentjs.com), which make it really easy to deal with dates in js, like this:

```
function dateToISO (date) {
    return moment(date).utc().format(); 
}
```

Comment: I have Moment.js installed, could you give the answer using it? thx

Comment: I Update my question, look at it and tell me if it works for you.